# Vuforia load White Rectangle instead of Video

Tags: unity-game-engine, vuforia

I have a problem with the app I'm building in Unity. I am using Vuforia to detect an image and to overlay it with a video. It works on the Unity editor, but when I use it on my android, it still detects the image but instead of the video it appears a white rectangle.
Does anyone know how to solve this? Thank you!

Comment: can you add more details , ho do you read video ? are u reading it from Application.PersistanceDatapath ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The format .mov wasn't working. I changed it to .mp4 and it worked!